# Assigning to a quosure in R / dplyr / rlang

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

Within a function, I want to update-in-place the values of columns specified by the user, where the user specified column names are captured via enquo(). So, here's a simplified example:

```
f1 <- function(df, x, y) {
    x <- enquo(x)
    y <- enquo(y)

    df %>%
        mutate((!! x) := (!! x)^2,
               (!! y) := (!! y)+1)
}

dat <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=10:1)
f1(dat, x=a, y=b)
```

This fails with an error: "The LHS of `:=` must be a string or a symbol".

I've also tried replacing, for example, `(!! x)` with `quo_get_expr(x)` and `f_text(x)`, but get the same error. For example:

```
f1 <- function(df, x, y) {
    x <- enquo(x)
    y <- enquo(y)

    df %>%
        mutate(quo_get_expr(x) := (!! x)^2,
               quo_get_expr(y) := (!! y)+1)
}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using R 4.1, dplyr 0.7.4, and rlang 0.2.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `quo_name`.  This works:

```
f1 <- function(df, x, y) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)

  df %>%
    mutate(
     !!quo_name(x) := (!!x)^2,
     !!quo_name(y) := (!!y)+1)
}

dat <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=10:1)
f1(dat, x=a, y=b)
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, @DaveBraze, this is my go-to for all things relating to `rlang`.  you've probably seen it, but my answer came straight from here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: I don't think I'd read that particular article, and I was googling around for rlang pointers, rather than dplyr. Thanks for the additional tip.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I see now that rlang::f_text() will work in exactly the same way as quo_name(), although it's not re-exported from dplyr.